# how to I preserve newlines while converting markdown from github to read-the-docs?

Tags: github, markdown, newline, read-the-docs

I am trying to convert some documentation from github to read-the-docs.
I came across an interesting issue where my newlines (aka line breaks aka /n) are getting lost in conversion. this happens with tooltips AND with summary/details

how to get multilines summaries and tooltips in read-the-docs?

for example:
my code inside github:

```
[tooltip_example_1]: ## "this is line 1 of my tooltip
this is line 2 of my tooltip"

this ia an example of [multiline tooltip][tooltip_example_1]


<details><summary> this is an example of a summary with multiple lines details </summary>
this is line 1 of my details.
    
this is line 2 of my details.
</details>
```

this is what it looks like in github with nice newlines.

[image]

but after building the pages in read-the-docs this is what it looks like:

tooltip tag is broken AND all my summary details on a single line

[image]

I tried to use /n, <brk>, etc...
I tried single and multiple empty lines...
I tried to google some solutions but so far no clear explanations nor solutions.
Ideally I would love to find a simple editor I could use to modify my read-the-docs directly as I am not specifically excited about github.

Comment: Did you try `<br>` as well?

Comment: so <br> half works!   thanks you. <br/>

It does work for the sumarry/details  but unfortunately it doesn't work for the tooltip .

Comment: I also tried <br/>  but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Read the Docs and mkdocs, but my guess is that tooltip and `<details>` tag aren't converted into HTML the same way in GitHub vs mkdocs.

**Details tag**

For the `<details>` tag, you probably need to use HTML directly for more control. That means using `<br>` to force a line break or you could wrap you lines in 2 different `<p>` tags or even use a `<ul>` list.

**Multi-line Tooltip**

For the tooltip, it could be that `mkdocs` doesn't support multi-line tooltips. If that's the case, it would be good to raise an issue about that in the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs).

In the meantime, you could always try:

```
[tooltip_example_2]: ## "this is line 1 of my tooltip&#10;this is line 2 of my tooltip"

this is an example of [multiline tooltip][tooltip_example_2]
```

Note here the use of the use of a [Decimal numeric character references](https://github.github.com/gfm/#decimal-numeric-character-references) to the line feed character (LF). This one works in GitHub, but I can't confirm if it works with mkdocs.

Comment: that works! &10 for tooltip and <br> for summary details!

Answer (score 0):

```
partial answer from @DecimalTum:

so <br> half works!   thanks you. <br/>

It does work for the sumarry/details  but unfortunately it doesn't work for the tooltip .


to be more precise: 

1) for the summart this works:
<details><summary> this is an example of a summary with multiple lines details </summary>
this is line 1 of my details.<br> 
this is line 2 of my details.<br>
</details>

2) for the tooltip this doesnt:

[tooltip_example_1]: ## "this is line 1 of my tooltip <br>this is line 2 of my tooltip"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).